# vim - can not exit with usual command

Tags: vim

[image: :]I have opened a file with vim on a so far unknown Linux server. What happens now is, I can not close the file or do anything. Usually, I can exit with <kbd>escape</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but when I do this, I get the error:

> E21: cannot make changes 'modifiable' is off

I get the same notice when I write anything else and press Enter. I simply cannot exit vim, even with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: are you pressing the `:` beteen escape and q so `<ESC>:q!<CR>` instead of `<ESC>q!<CR>` which you wrote in the question?. Maybe a stupid question but the picture is revealing an macro recording, which is on `q` in normal mode

Comment: The top image is of a help file. Those can't be modified. The second image shows that you're recording a macro, which as @DoktorOSwaldo points out, means you didn't press the : key before q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>. Note: they are both uppercase. so it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. This is equivalent to `:q!` which you should use instead of `q!`

Answer (score 1):

Try to press in your keyboard **Ctrl + L** and the write de command `:q!`
That happend tome before, I couldnt even write '**:**'

Answer (score 0):

try to write this code in vim command
  :set ma
that'll make the file modifiable

Comment: Even when I write: 'set ma', I'll get an "E21: cannot make changes 'modifiable' is off".

Answer (score 0):

You need to **set** the modifiable option which will allow you to modify the buffer. To do that execute the following statement inside your **Vim** editor.

> `:set modifiable`

Also,later you might want to set the modifiable option off (*opposite of what you want.*)

> `:set noma`

Then, you may exit your **Vim**.

Comment: Even when I write: 'set modifiable', I'll get an "E21: cannot make changes 'modifiable' is off".

Comment: The problem might be with one of your Vim plugins, have you tried uninstalling them and checking again ?

Comment: As I can not exit VIM at all, I can not install or uninstall anything - I simply need any advice to exit vim.

Comment: Try running `:verbose set modifiable?` to find out if a plugin is setting the option. If the option has been modified by a plugin, it will show `Last set from /path/to/plugin/file` (in addition to showing the value).

Comment: WHATEVER I write after the colon, I always get an `E21`

Comment: Are you able to share a screenshot with us ? Or comment the exact words from your Vim.